# Problem in my bitmap colors - how to fix that?

Tags: android, bitmap

I have problem with the color of image after hiding secret message ,I update the code ,by uploading full code , please help me ,I in the first steps in android .

//this to get PNG image from drawable

```
drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.penguins1);
    BitmapDrawable abmp = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
    //***the original image
    srcImg = abmp.getBitmap();

    //this image resulted after hide message
    newimage = Bitmap.createBitmap(srcImg.getWidth(), srcImg.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 );
//this function contain the settings of image and arrays
set_hide();
//this function for hidding operation` 
Least_Hide_fract();
//the following code for converting 3 resulted arrays into bmp image
for (int i = 0; i < newimage.getWidth(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < newimage.getHeight(); j++) {

        byte Red = (Range_R[i][j]);
        byte Green = (Range_G[i][j]);
        byte Blue = (Range_B[i][j]);
        byte alpha = (byte) alpha(srcImg.getPixel(i,j));
                newimage.setPixel(i, j, Color.argb(alpha, Red, Green, Blue));
            }}
imagev.setImageBitmap(newimage);

  //save image after hiding to file
String folder_main = "saveimage";
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),folder_main);
if(!dir.exists()) {dir.mkdirs();}
File  file = new File(dir,"secretimage.png");

try{
    OutputStream stream ;
    stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    newimage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,stream);
    stream.flush();
    stream.close();
}catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

// Parse the saved image path to uri
 Uri savedImageURI = Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath());

// Display the saved image to ImageView
 imagev.setImageURI(savedImageURI);

// Display saved image uri to TextView
tv_saved.setText("Image saved in external storage.\n" + savedImageURI);
```

**[source image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnCQ6.png)**

**[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RyLUg.png)**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188160/discussion-on-question-by-sudad-najim-problem-in-my-bitmap-colors-how-to-fix-t). If you are asked for additional information, please [edit] it into the question.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the function `srcImg.getPixel(i, j)` does not return the alpha color value as you expect. It returns the whole color (ARGB) as integer.

So you first have to extract the alpha value of the int:

```
int alpha = alpha(srcImg.getPixel(i, j));
int myAlpha = (alpha >> 24) & 0xff;
newimage.setPixel(i, j, Color.argb( myAlpha, Red, Green, Blue));
```

Comment: I tried your answer , but no change ...any other idea?